# What is rate limit of accessing Telegram bot APIs?

Tags: telegram

I read in the docs that bot can send:

- 30 messages/second to different chats
- 1 message per second to the same chat
- 20 messages per minute to the same group chat

but this is all about sending messages, what about other endpoints? more specifically `getChatMembersCount` method?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a long time, but there's a very good resource now - https://limits.tginfo.me/en. There's a Bots section there. Also if you have time you can send pull request to the github repository - https://github.com/tginfo/Telegram-Limits/

Comment: yeah, it didn't help. TS has more info about the limits than this website.